# Unity 3D inside Android Studio

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, 360-virtual-reality

I have an Android app and it  has three options. What I want is when I click the first button it should open a Android VR app made in Unity  which has a 360 degree video. When I click the second button it should open a Android 3D unity game. So that I can see this in carboard. For the third option there is just a survey, which is simple. But my question is how to do the first two button part .

Comment: AFAIK, can't do, you should make the whole app in unity3D, it's easier to do, and you will only have 1 app for everything. I guess you could open them from android, but it might require the 2 other apps to be downloaded and installed by the user

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question, what you want to do is just to open another app (actually 2) from buttons 1 and 2?

There is a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800900/android-launch-another-app-from-activity)
where it explains how to open another app from an activity (in android). You should be able to adapt the code there to the click event on your buttons.

If what you want is to open "different" instances of your app, or just different screens, I would strongly recommend to build everything in Unity, so you have everything in 1 place (assuming that they are your apps as well). Otherwise the solution of just launching a new app should do the trick.