# Android - launching another app's most recent activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I'd like my app to be able to launch any other app - but instead of launching the other-app's main activity (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800900/android-launch-another-app-from-activity)), I'd like to be able to launch the other-app's most recent activity.

In other words, I want to programmatically have the same user experience that the user gets when clicking on the "recent apps" system/hardware button, and selecting any app from the list.

Not sure if that's even possible with the current [Android API](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/index.html), or perhaps I didn't use it the right way.

Thanks!

Comment: Selecting an app from recents doesn't necessarily launch its most recent activity.

Answer (score -1):

It depends of the `launchMode`of the other app´s activity !

Comment: Can you please elaborate or link to reference?

Comment: this reading will help you: https://www.mobomo.com/2011/06/android-understanding-activity-launchmode/  Please upvote!